# Flask/Python denying existing logic conditionally

Tags: python, flask

I got two types of registration and can't figure out what to if by accident user selects both. Basically I want to prioritise one of the logic in case user have both the options. Following is the explanation and conditions I am trying to code.

1. User can register with the schools allowed to register free.
2. User can also register if he/she has the coupon.
3. If user's school is in list and user has coupon then he should be registered on behalf of university and coupon will not be used by backend.

   ```
       my_school = form.university.data
       waiverlist = ['A', 'B', 'C']
       if my_school in waiverlist:
           package = Package(
               student_id=profile_data.id,
               stripe_id = 'N/A For Group Subscriber',
               student_email= profile_data.email,
               is_active=True,
               package_type='PartnerSubscription',
               subscription_id='N/A For Group Subscriber'
               )
           dbase.session.add(package)
           dbase.session.commit()

       cp = Coupons.query.filter_by(coupon=Coupons.coupon).first()
       if cp:
           mycoupon = form.coupon.data
           print mycoupon
           print cp.coupon
           if form.coupon.data==cp.coupon:
               package = Package(
                   student_id=profile_data.id,
                   stripe_id = 'N/A For Group Subscriber',
                   student_email= profile_data.email,
                   is_active=True,
                   package_type='GroupSubsciption',
                   subscription_id='N/A For Group Subscriber'
                   )
               dbase.session.add(package)
               dbase.session.commit()

       return redirect('/profile')
   ```

With above code it creates two database entries. Actually i tried with elif but couldn't make it work.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply making the coupon check `if cp and my_school not in waiverlist`

Or even better make both conditional blocks of code into functions. Then call the coupon function only with a condition check that will return a call to the school function:

```
# I don't know what other variables you'd need, so kwargs
def register_with_coupon(school, **kwargs):
    if school in waiver_list:
        return register_with_school()
    #insert with coupon
```